# SWAN doesn't run

Tags: oceanography, wind, waves, wave-modeling

I'm Ocean Engineering Master Student. I'm not an expert in SWAN. I have some problem with it. Previously my result like rotated so I take another option to make grids using GridBuilder but SWAN doesn't work. This is my script. The error is Severe error: At least, FLOW and FHIGH or MSC must be given! I think the FLOW and FHIGH already exist. What should I do? Thanks

Best Regards
Rahmadimi

PROJECT 'tesis' 's2'

$Input Data
SET LEVEL 0.0 depmin 0.1 maxerr=2 inrhog=1 NAUT
MODE NONSTAT TWOD
COORD SPHE

$grid input
CGRID CURVILINEAR 114 414 EXC -9999 CIRCLE 36 flow=0.04 fhigh=1 40
READGRID COORDINATES 1 'test2.grd' 4 0 0 FREE

$Bathymetri Input-
INPGRID BOTTOM CURVILINEAR 0 0 114 414 EXC -9999
READINP BOTTOM 1 'test2.bot' 4 0 FREE

$Wind Input
INPGRID WIND REGular 78 -15.5 0.0 337 93 0.25 0.25 &
NONSTAT 20190201.000000 6 HR 20190201.180000
READINP WIND 1.00 'Feb1uv.txt' 2 0 FREE

$Boundary Setting
BOUND SHAP PM

$Initial Condition
INITIAL DEFAULT

$Paramater Setting
GEN3 KOMEN AGROW
WCAP
QUAD
TRIAD
BREAKING
DIFFRAC
FRICTION

$ NUMERICAL CALCULATION

PROP BSBT
NUM ACCUR npnts=95. STAT mxitst=15

$ _________________ OUTPUT DISPLAY ______________________________________
BLOCK 'COMPGRID' NOHEAD 'Feb19-1-1.mat' LAY 3 XP YP FRAME WIND HSIGN DIR PTHSIGN PTDIR OUT 20190201.000000 6 HR 
$end
COMP NONSTAT 20190201.000000 6 HR 20190201.180000
STOP

Comment: Please don't post a duplicate of your first question if it has not been answered yet.